# Is it against official policy to be helpful and point new users in the right direction when they ask an inappropriate question?

Tags: discussion

Shouldn't a link to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14/photography-chat) be the first thing we would offer a new user who asks [something like this](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/96932/15871)? At times it seems like we want to run new people off! We obviously have no trouble telling a new user why "we don't/can't do that here" but apparently we don't know how to post a link to chat...

Answer (score 5):

No, it's not against any policy to be helpful.

Here's some helpful information: users with less than 20 reputation points cannot talk in chat.

Comment: Thanks for that helpful tidbit. I can't remember ever not being able to post in chat. I guess I already had 20 points the first time I tried.

Comment: Can a lower rep user participate in a specific chat room created for that user and a few others, rather than the general chat room for each SE site?

Comment: Only a diamond-carrying moderator can lift the restriction (for a specific user in a specific room), the process is [described here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/111946).

Comment: @FTP also converting comments to chat will also add the user automatically, but spawning a list of however many comments it takes to activate that probably isn't an ideal work around.

Answer (score 1):

Current advice (from my limited perspective) seems to be to give constructive feedback when downvoting. FWIW - I'm posting this 13 hours after you asked, and the question is already gone.

Perhaps the policy should be to put a little *extra* effort in when the question is being asked by a 1 rep user. For Example:

- Don't downvote without a comment
- If the comment is "this doesn't belong here" - then answer the question, where *does* it belong and how can I help OP get there?

I guess it comes back to goals. But, if a goal is to add additional, active users to the community, then the policy needs to reflect a bit more help to new users. Or at least, avoidance of some of the immediate hostility.

A link to chat would be great, if only it were a universal privilege. (My chat privileges were granted by the system not that long ago)